# update firebase database from current user

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want to store image in firebase storage and create url than update value from my current database in firebase, but it didn't store in firebase database from current user. this is my code, where I do wrong?

```
fileprivate func saveToFirebase(image: UIImage) {
    guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }
    let uuidName = UUID().uuidString

    Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(uuidName).putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print(" -- Failed to upload images -- ")
            print(" -- \(err) -- ")
            return
        }

        metadata?.storageReference?.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print(" -- Failed to create URL -- ")
                print(" -- \(err) -- ")
                return
            }

            guard let profileImageURL = url?.absoluteString else { return }
            guard let currentUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
            let userProfileURL = ["profileImageURL": profileImageURL]

            Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUID).updateChildValues(userProfileURL, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reference) in
            if let err = error {
                    print(" -- Failed to create URL -- ")
                    print(" -- \(err) -- ")
                    return
                }
                print("✅ -- Successfully update user data -- ✅")
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You have several situations that could result in silent failure, such as your guard statements returning void, and the optionally chained call to download the metadata URL. Add some comments to those parts of your code so you can distinguish exactly what it is that's causing the issue.

Comment: @Callam so I need to use if let than guard let?

Comment: My money is on one of the properties in the chain being nil when you try `metadata?.storageReference?.downloadURL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly we can create an enum to represent the different failures that could occur. Some scenarios we consider to be errors (such as a guard else returning void, or a broken chained optional) fail silently. Here we can encapsulate the different failure scenarios that need to be handled.

```
enum ProfileImageUploadError: Error {
    case unauthenticatedUser
    case invalidImageData
    case failedDataUpload(Error?)
    case failedDownloadURL(Error?)
    case failedProfileUpdate(Error?)

    var localizedDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .failedDataUpload: return "Failed to upload data"
        case .failedDownloadURL: return "Failed to download URL"
        case .failedProfileUpdate: return "Failed to update profile"
        default: return "\(self)"
        }
    }

    var underlyingError: Error? {
        switch self {
        case .failedDataUpload(let err): return err
        case .failedDownloadURL(let err): return err
        case .failedProfileUpdate(let err): return err
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Next, we can immediately determine that we have an authenticated user and that the image data checks out. When a guard fails, we call the completion block passing the error case for that scenario. Keeping this up, we construct our references to the storage and database providers, and attempt the sequence catching errors.

Given there is no error initially uploading the data, we can assume the image has been uploaded. Also rather than using the optional metadata, we can use the storage ref we constructed earlier to download the URL.

As we continue through the sequence of operations, we're trying to sufficiently handle what we consider to be the errors, until successful completion upon which point we can return the URL saved to Firebase Database.

```
func uploadProfileImage(_ image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (URL?, ProfileImageUploadError?) -> ()) {

    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        return completion(nil, .unauthenticatedUser)
    }

    guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else {
        return completion(nil, .invalidImageData)
    }

    let storagePath = "profile_images/\(UUID().uuidString)"
    let databasePath = "users/\(currentUser.uid)/profileImageURL"

    let profileImageDataRef = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: storagePath)
    let profileImageURLRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: databasePath)

    profileImageDataRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            return completion(nil, .failedDataUpload(error))
        }

        profileImageDataRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            guard let profileImageURL = url?.absoluteString else {
                return completion(nil, .failedDownloadURL(error))
            }

            profileImageURLRef.setValue(profileImageURL, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                guard error == nil else {
                    return completion(nil, .failedProfileUpdate(error))
                }

                completion(url, nil)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, this is how you would use the function inside your existing one.

```
fileprivate func saveToFirebase(image: UIImage) {
    uploadProfileImage(image) { (url, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(" -- \(error.localizedDescription) -- ")
            print(" -- \(error.underlyingError.debugDescription) -- ")
        } else {
            print("✅ -- Successfully update user data -- ✅")
            print("✅ -- \(url.debugDescription) -- ✅")
        }
    }
}
```

*This is not tested*

So to recap, some of the lines in your function can 'fail' silently, this can be resolved by sufficiently handling the 'optionals' and errors with completions or simply print statements. I think it is the chain of optional properties leading up to the URL download causing the issue – specifically the metadata property in `metadata?.storageReference?.downloadURL`.

Comment: Hey @Callam thank you it work beautifully, I never use enum before like you did to handle error.  learn a lot from you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this..
useruid is firbase uid

```
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(useruid)
                storageRef.putData(imagedata, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadatas, error) in
                    if error != nil {                                              
                     print("Couldn't Upload Image")
                                    } else {
                                        print("Uploaded")
                                      print(metadatas!)
                                        storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                                            if error != nil {
                                                print(error!)
                                                return

                                            }
                                            if url != nil {

                          let imageurl = String(describing: url!)
                         print(imageurl)                                            }
                                        })
                            }
                })
```